# How do credit scores work? How do they differ from credit ratings?

Tags: credit-score

I've heard both these terms used - are they synonymous?  Or is one for Canada, one for the U.K. (or U.S.)?

What are the various factors go into determining an individual's "credit score"?

Comment: I think they're synonymous.  That being said, this is mostly a duplicate question of http://www.basicallymoney.com/questions/163/what-is-a-fico-score-and-how-is-it-related-to-a-credit-report which was asking about FICO scores.  FICO is just one "brand" of credit score, but I think the answer is generally applicable to credit scores.

Comment: I'll leave this question open though in case there is a distinction I'm not aware of!  :-)

Comment: Thanks :) I was certain I had checked for duplicates, but I had never heard of "FICO" before now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Credit ratings are the same as credit score**, but they very different from a *credit report*.

A credit score is a calculated number based on a usually secret formula that attempts to quantify with math a consistent number that ranks everybody equally and uniformly as to the risk they present to a lender.

Basically, we are all just a number; the higher the better.

Your credit report is a detailed list of all your accounts, how well you pay them and if you are behind or have settled them as agreed.  It is a detailed history of how you use credit, who you have credit from, how long you have had credit, and how much credit and debt you carry.

A credit report relies on lenders honestly and accurately stating how your account is performing with them.  Some radio show hosts (Clark Howard) say that up to 70% of United States citizens have a mistake on their credit reports.

The credit report is the source of values that are computed into your credit score.

By and large, your credit score gives a lender a good idea if you are acceptable, but if you number is on the line, they MIGHT choose to read your credit report to make a decision by a human.  Your credit score is how retail stores can offer and immediately approve store cards.  If you number is high enough, credit you get.

Source:  https://www.annualcreditreport.com/

**EDIT:**  I didn't read well the first time, but sine I typed it I will leave it here.  Sorry for rushing and not reading well.

Comment: Good to know but she was asking about Credit "Rating" vs. Credit Score not Credit "Report".

Comment: Oh snap!  I will leave it but that was a lot of wrong answer there wasn't it?

Comment: I would bold-face "Credit ratings are the same as credit score" at the very top and leave the rest alone.  It's a fine answer.

Comment: Thanks for this, MrChrister!  And Chris W. Rea for the clarification.